# Setting a custom font

Tags: android, fonts

I'm trying to set a custom font to my game, but I really don't know how. The way I choose the font at the moment is using this method

```
    public void loadFont() {
    font = FontFactory.createStroke(activity.getFontManager(), activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD), 50,
            true, Color.WHITE_ABGR_PACKED_INT, 2, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
    font.load();
}
```

Where "Typeface.SANS_SERIF" is the font

If you know how I could load a font from the assets folder could you please help me? Thank you

****I am using AndEngine-GLES2-AnchorCenter

Answer (score 2):

Add your `yourfont.ttf` or `yourfont.otf` into `Assets` in your `Project` and load custom font like

```
Typeface tf = null;
tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Helvetica neue.ttf");
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextview); 
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Here's the code

```
public void loadFont() {
        font = FontFactory.createStroke(activity.getFontManager(), activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, Typeface.create(Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/CUSTOMFONTNAME.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD), 50,
                true, Color.TRANSPARENT_ABGR_PACKED_INT, 2, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
        font.load();
```

Comment: that is great :) +1 for question and answer both  than

Answer (score 0):

hi please do like this

```
   public void loadFont() {
            font = FontFactory.createStroke(activity.getFontManager(), activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, Typeface.create(Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/CUSTOMFONTNAME.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD), 50,
                    true, Color.TRANSPARENT_ABGR_PACKED_INT, 2, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
            font.load();}
```

if there is any text view than

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "yourfont.ttf");
    text.setTypeface(font);
```

beside this visit my blog http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-customfont.html and do it in this way

Programaticaaly you can do as follows, You can create subclass for each TextView, Button, etc. and apply custom font in the constructor:

```
public class BrandTextView extends TextView {

      public BrandTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
          super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      }
     public BrandTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
      }
     public BrandTextView(Context context) {
          super(context);
     }
     public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
           if (style == Typeface.BOLD) {
                super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/YourCustomFont_Bold.ttf"));
            } else {
               super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/YourCustomFont.ttf"));
            }
      }
 }
```

Then just use that custom views instead of standard ones (i.e. BrandTextView instead of TextView).

```
<com.your.package.BrandTextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="View with custom font"/>
<com.your.package.BrandTextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:text="View with custom font and bold typeface"/>
```

use these all in yours main.xml and you can use them

another possible way can be as follows as well

```
FontHelper.applyFont(context, findViewById(R.id.activity_root), "fonts/YourCustomFont.ttf");

where applyFont method acn be written as follows

public static void applyFont(final Context context, final View root, final String fontName) {
        try {
            if (root instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) root;
                for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
                    applyFont(context, viewGroup.getChildAt(i), fontName);
            } else if (root instanceof TextView)
                ((TextView) root).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontName));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Error occured when trying to apply %s font for %s view", fontName, root));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

please visit for more better understanding http://vision-apps.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-better-way-to-apply-custom-font.html

Comment: Parts of the answer seem to be directly copied from vision-apps.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-better-way-to-apply-custom-font.html - please add attribution when you're using other people's work.

Comment: @laalto i have added the attribution and the link  http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-customfont.html is of my own blog as well

Answer (score 0):

In Andengine-GLES2 you can use custom font this way in onCreateResources():

```
    FontFactory.setAssetBasePath("font/");
    final ITexture fontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);

    this.mFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(this.getFontManager(), fontTexture, activity.getAssets(), "your_font_name.ttf", 40, true, android.graphics.Color.BLACK);       
    this.mFont.load();
```

You can use "Typeface.SANS_SERIF" font this way:

```
    this.mFont = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL), 32);
    this.mFont.load();
```